Non-Persistent Singleton in Firebase Cloud Functions
I'm working on a Firebase project with Cloud Functions and Firestore.
The main challenge I'm facing is ensuring that a singleton (or any "global" object which is used such that different parts of the code during a function execution have access to it without needing to pass it through multiple layers) is non-persistent across Cloud function invocations, i.e. the singleton object shall only exist in-memory during a single invocation of a Cloud Function and shall not be shared across different invocations.
Is is possible to achieve this in Firebase Cloud Functions?

What you're describing is not a "global variable" at all, and not really a singleton either.  What you need is a variable that you only allocate per-invocation and pass around to the various other software components that require it.  Cloud Functions doesn't offer any sort of storage that's only accessible per invocation - you have to write your own code for this.

What I want is to have an instance of an object which is declared and exported outside the Cloud function itself, such that that instance can be accessed from other parts of the code during the function invocation, and is "cleared" afterwards. Is this not possibble?

Like I said, you have to write code to accomplish that.  Maybe a dependency injection framework will help, but what you're trying to do is neither simple nor free.  It's not even unique to Cloud Functions.

Thanks, a dependency injection framework  seems to be the way to go!
